# Did we find any exo–dwarf-planet?

Tags: exoplanet, dwarf-planets

We have discovered thousands of exoplanets so far. Do we categorize them into planets and dwarf planets, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There is no reason why one wouldn't. But we don't know any exo-dwarf planets (yet). See the answer [to this question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/41179/what-are-the-challenges-in-finding-earth-like-planets-via-the-radial-velocity-me) why.